# Python Selenium Get Text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

When I try to click on an xpayh that contains some text, it rises an error

> > 'str' object is not callable

Code:

```py
some_text = 'GET'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//*[contains(text(), '" + some_text + "')]")).click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a wrong syntax.
Try this:

```py
some_text = 'GET'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), '" + some_text + "')]").click()
```